# d3.text load text file with async/await api return promise

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to load a text file with d3.text api as below, but it return a promise. I would expect it return the text file content.

```js
async function loadSync(filename) {
    return await d3.text(filename)
}

function load_address() {
    var url = "https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt"
    var addrs = loadSync(url)
    console.log(addrs)
}

load_address()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, you're right that the result is a promise. Be sure to `await` within an `async function` at the appropriate time.

Second, you'll need to work around the Cross-origin policy issue with a CORS Proxy.

```js
async function load_address() {
    let proxy = 'https://corsproxy.io/?'
    var url = "https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt"
    var addrs = await d3.text(proxy + url)
    console.log(addrs)
}

load_address()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, this is pretty easy to do with `fetch` as well:

```
fetch("https://corsproxy.io/?https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt").then(
  async function(r) {
  console.log(await r.text())
 }
)
```

Comment: Great, but what’s the reason to use two times await?

Comment: Really, You only need one `await`; I only had two since I was building on your code. The simplified the code so that there's only one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to fetch the file first and then do the other things